# SharePoint 2013 RestAPI retrieve Task and subtask Parent id undefined

Tags: sharepoint-rest-api, task-list

I am trying to retrieve the sub-task of the parent task from a list.
query:

> ../_api/web/lists/getbytitle('Tasks')/items?$select=Title,Status,ParentID/Id&$expand=ParentID

**Code:**

```
function onQuerySucceeded(data) {
    var mainTasks = [];
    var subTasks = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
        if (data[i].ParentID.Id) {
            subTasks.push(data[i]);
        } else {
            mainTasks.push(data[i]);
        }

    }
    $.each(data.d.results, function (key, value) {
        subTasks += '<strong>Title: </strong> ' + value.Title +
            ' <strong>Status:</strong> ' + value.Status + ' <strong>Parent Id:</strong> ' + value.Id +
            '<br />';
    });

    $("#divSubTaskItems").html(subTasks);

};
```

My results are:

> undefined: "Title:  Test rest Call Status: In Progress Parent Id:
>   undefined"

Answer (score 1):

Try adding `console.log(value);` inside your $.each to see what data you have:

```
$.each(data.d.results, function (key, value) {
    console.log(value);
    subTasks += '<strong>Title: </strong> ' + value.Title +
        ' <strong>Status:</strong> ' + value.Status + ' <strong>Parent Id:</strong> ' + value.Id +
        '<br />';
});
```

Most likely, value.Id is indeed undefined. This is because you don't request it

Try this REST query instead:

> ?$select=Title,Status,Predecessors,**Predecessors/Id**&$expand=**Predecessors**

[image]